# Using pdflatex with other languages than English

Tags: latex

I am using latex to compose a letter.  It works well in English, but how can I handle other languages (Spanish, French).  Emacs actually prints the foreign characters, but when I run `pdflatex`on the file, `pdflatex` complains on some of the characters.

Comment: pdflatex handles UTF-8 with difficulty. Use a more modern, UTF-8 aware processor, like `xelatex` or `lualatex`. But the question has nothing to do with emacs. You should take it to the [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a french document that should compile fine with pdflatex.
I think you can adapt it to provide a similar document for spanish.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Dès Noël, où un zéphyr haï me vêt de glaçons würmiens, je dîne
d’exquis rôtis de bœuf au kir, à l’aÿ d’âge mûr, \&cætera
\end{document}
```

Comment: You also need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if you are using UTF-8 (and if not, you should!).

Comment: I get LaTeX Error: Unicode character ħ (U+0127) not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple languages in a single document (e.g. in situations requiring original citations in other languages than document class of document)?

Comment: Please take this whole discussion to TeX SE - it has nothing to do with emacs. And actually before doing that, *search* TeX SE: these questions have been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can opt to use LuaLatex instead of the default engine.

```
(setq TeX-engine 'luatex)
```